# Record Keyboard Macros in C#

Tags: c#, macros

How do I set my application to record keyboard macros. Like Shift-Alt-I would open Internet Explorer. I know that this feature is avaliable in Windows, but I don't think it's very good. I have a textbox control and a button that says "Record keyboard Macro".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using KeyDown & KeyUp events and capturing the keys pressed.

Have a look at this article on Key Processing Techniques:
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/29/keys.html